# Excel - Creating a print macro

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro to print an excel sheet when the button is pressed. But I want to specify the printer that it automatically prints to rather than give the user a choice. I'm also printing to a PDF so is there a way I can choose where I print to?

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Publish()
    '
    ' Publish Macro
    ' Macro recorded 07/09/2010
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+S
    '
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
    End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't prevent the user from selecting a different printer. Just default to your selection. What if the only allowed printer is broken or replaced? What if the user is working from home?

Comment: A PDF program can't break. And I'm setting this macro to a button. It's not like they still can't press print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

`Application.ActivePrinter = "Printer Name"`

on the line above the PrintOut command.  [This link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216026) gives more information on ActivePrinter, even though it is geared more for MS Word.

Comment: Awesome, that works. Is there a way to specify the location as well?

Comment: What do you mean by location?  The name of the PDF file that you want to create?